# Drawable Resource cannot parse selector tag in XML

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I'm having a problem regarding the selector tag in drawable resources. Eclipse can't parse it, and I tried building it manually using aapk but to no avail.
[See pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEIFL.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xlmns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:constantSize="true">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_selres"
      android:state_selected="false"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_unselres"
      android:state_selected="true"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: Can u paste the whole selector code there? Maybe there is some illegal white character?

Comment: Yes, I did. The problem is that the selector tag was never available in the first place when I click Ctrl+Space, which is supposed to give code hints.

Comment: That's not the problem - in my eclipse the hint feature is not working either there, but the selectors are working as intended.

Comment: I posted the code if it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found where the error lies :)

Change :
`xlmns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

to
`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

You mispelled the word `xmlns`.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see line covered by error message. Is there `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` ?